# Difference between PerspectiveCamera and matrixCamera

Tags: wpf, 3d

i'm trying to create a 3D animation using WPF. To modelize a form i see that we can use PerspectiveCamera or matrixCamera. What's the difference between the both?

Comment: There's also an orthogonal camera

Answer (score 1):

Perspective camera makes objects farther away look smaller, like what we see in real life or through a camera zoom lens.  You can achieve the same thing using a matrix camera, but you can also do a lot more.  The perspective camera and orthogonal camera are both special cases of the more general matrix camera.  With a matrix camera, you could create a perspective in one dimension different from the other, like a panorama view.  It requires more work than the other camera types to do the same thing, but has more possibilities.